# Configuration management for developers' desktops

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, puppet, salt-stack

I work in a small software development outfit, ~30 developers. We develop a Java-based web app that uses JDK, Apache Tomcat, MySQL & Solr running on CentOS servers. Most devs use windows laptops, some use Macs. They run a "copy" of the production servers in a VM on their laptop using VirtualBox. They develop using Eclipse or IntelliJ in the host OS but they deploy to the guest OS using shell scripts that they run from the guest (which in turn pull files from the host OS via shared folders). So nothing special really. Right now the devs pass around an external HD which a VirtualBox image on it which gets updated every now and again (but not always). But mostly the updates are via email blasts saying "run these cmds in your VM to slightly update the JVM" or similar.

Obviously we need Vagrant. But I'm not certain if we should be using SaltStack or Puppet or Chef etc? For a relatively simple env like this, one local VM only, non-linuxy developers whom I'd prefer avoid the cmd line as much as possible, what might be the best mix here for a solution?

Comment: In this particular case, it does not matter what software you will use. If you have developers to manage the provisioning scripts, start with Chef, it is considered more friendly for them than the others.

Comment: Being a developer I'd strongly advise on having a standard Vagrantfile with Puppet provisioner in use and a slew of Puppet modules from the Forge[https://forge.puppetlabs.com]. As noted above pretty much any provisioner is cool - I just find Puppet more intuitive.

Comment: Thanks guys, your comments are helpful.